# Opening a Google map in a jquery modal window whenever I hover over a specific location

Tags: jquery, hover, maps, modal-dialog

I have a table with separate locations in each cell. What I need to happen is whenever I hover or click the cell with the location in it a google map will appear in a jquery modal window. Thanks for any help that can be provided since I am a javascript and a beginner with google maps api.

Thanks

Comment: Please, provide us at least your table and the code you tried to reach your goal. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good solution:

http://wordpressthemescollection.com/simple-modal-google-map-easy-modal-map-boxes-with-jquery-752.html

You can amend the code there to use either the hover or the click class.